# List vs Data frame

Tags: r

I imported a 150K row 40 col csv file into R. When I do:

```
typeof(mydata)
```

I get:

```
[1] "list"
```

However,

```
is.data.frame(mydata)
```

returns

```
TRUE
```

After spending a lot of time trying to convert mydata to a dataframe (after getting the first result) rather than a list, was I wasting my time?

Why the different results?

Comment: you'll get better and more prompt responses if your example is self-contained. what i mean is that you should show the minimum code needed to generate the `mydata`, where the problem/confusion occurs, and what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not wasting your time, since you learned something ;-)

Use `class` instead of `typeof`:

```
class(mydata)
```

The reason of the result reported by `typeof` may be that, under the hood, a `data.frame` is basically a list of columns.

Comment: ...also note that the documentation for `typeof` makes it clear that it returns the _internal_ type of an object, and the possible values does not even include data.frame at all.